# Redirect after submitting a form (HTML, PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have made a test which is divided over a couple of pages. Then when people click the submit button, I want to redirect them, after saving, to the next page. For some reason, a submit button submits and then immediately refreshes the page. So the javascript for redirecting is not even run.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="formwrap">
  <!-- questions here -->
  <input id="submitButton" class="block" type = "submit" name = "verzenden" value = "Opslaan" onClick="nextPage();"/>
</form>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
function nextPage() {
  window.location.href = "test.php";
}
```

Any ideas? I've already tried: making the input type="button" and then making a javascript submit function; in the `<form>` tag `onSubmit="nextPage()";` Things with `preventDefault`, to prevent the submit button from reloading the page.

I get the feeling that it's a MUST for a submit button to reload or something. So maybe there is a way to redirect AFTER reloading the page.
Well, I have no idea. Any help would be more than welcome!

Comment: Why not just use a submit button that has a target of the next page?

Comment: These are 2 javascript things I have tried..
function submitForm() { document.forms["formwrap"].submit();}
document.getElementById("submitButton").addEventListener("click", function(e) {e.preventDefault();});

Comment: Agree with @TimTroiano his suggestion

Comment: Your submit button is a SUBMIT button. Clicking it loads the action URL of the form. In this case, it is the current URL. It looks like you want a button of type button, not an input of type submit.

Comment: How would I make a submit button target the next page? target="url" doesn't seem to be a valid attribute..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, remove the inline handler on your submit button. Your HTML should look like so:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="formwrap">
  <!-- questions here -->
  <input id="submitButton" class="block" type="submit" name="verzenden" value="Opslaan" />
</form>
```

Then, update your JavaScript to add an event handler that targets your `formwrap` element's `submit` event. Then prevent the form from making a post-back with `preventDefault`. Once the default behavior is prevented, you can send the user to whatever url you want :)

```
document
  .getElementById("formwrap")
  .addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = "test.php";
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did that, but for some reason, I'm still not redirected to the new page..

Comment: where and how are you declaring your javascript? You may want to put the script tag before the closing body tag or wrap it in a dom ready callback or sorts.

Comment: I have a fiddle with it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/sethkrasnianski/mrbxv2dj/. So something's wrong with your implementation.

Comment: I just put script tags in the head, am now trying it in body. Otherwise maybe in a real JS file.

Comment: You sir, are a genius. Thanks so much! It works! Now let's hope it still submits the form.. :P

Comment: File vs script tag isn't the real issue. Although it's nice to separate your concerns with that pattern. But putting it in your footer should do the trick.

Comment: Then one more questions comes to mind: Why does the JavaScript not work in the <head> tags, but does work in the <body> tags?

Comment: Glad I could help. That's because the dom hasn't loaded, so when you add the event listeners in the head, you're attaching to nodes that don't exist yet, therefore you're not really doing anything. Doing so in the footer ensures that the html before it has loaded. Thus ensuring that you can effectively use your javascript. the other option is to use a dom loaded callback such as `DOMContentLoaded` or jquery's `document.ready`

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks again for the help :D

Comment: this does not submit the form dude